# Parsing XML with MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue parsing XML with SQL2008. I've tried this 100 different ways and can't get any data out.

I am trying to get data like Title, date_start out of the XML.

The XML is going into my #xml1 table – I can select from @XMLtable or #xml1 and see the XML in the column.

Here is the XML:

```
<VacancyList xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.com/list.xsd">
<Vacancy id="1238059" date_start="2014-08-12">
    <Versions>
        <Version language="en">
            <Title>Web Developer  </Title>
            <TitleHeading/>
            <Categories>
                <Item type="area-of-interest" id="32203">SQL</Item>
                <Item type="duration" id="permanent">Permanent</Item>
                <Item type="extent" id="fulltime">Full-time</Item>
                <Item type="operating-time" id="day">Day</Item>
            </Categories>
        </Version>
    </Versions>
    </Vacancy>
    <Vacancy id="1238059" date_start="2014-07-14">
    <Versions>
        <Version language="en">
            <Title>DBA  </Title>
            <TitleHeading/>
            <Categories>
                <Item type="area-of-interest" id="32203">Oracle</Item>
                <Item type="duration" id="permanent">Permanent</Item>
                <Item type="extent" id="fulltime">Full-time</Item>
                <Item type="operating-time" id="day">Day</Item>
            </Categories>
        </Version>
    </Versions>
</Vacancy>
</VacancyList>
```

Here is my SQL:

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml1
CREATE TABLE #xml1 ( yourXML XML )
GO

DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @URL = 'https://URLofTheXMLFeed.com/list.xml'

DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 

INSERT #xml1 ( yourXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 

Declare @XMLOutput xml
SET @XMLOutput = (SELECT yourXML FROM #xml1)

SELECT
 val.value('(Title/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Title
FROM
  #xml1
CROSS APPLY yourXML.nodes('//Vacancy') AS Txn(svc)
CROSS APPLY svc.nodes('Versions') AS svc(rsp)
CROSS APPLY rsp.nodes('Version') as rsp(val)
```

Comment: Note: No errors - just no results.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect as output? A list of job title?

Comment: Zoff - Ultimately I want to get some different fields from the XML, but for sake of the issue, I'd be happy to get just one, so I chose title.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` statement is more complicated than it needs to be:

```
Declare @XMLOutput xml
SET @XMLOutput = (SELECT yourXML FROM #xml1)

SELECT      x.value('Title[1]','varchar(100)')
FROM        @XMLOutput.nodes('/VacancyList/Vacancy/Versions/Version')   t(x)
```

Also, your XML is invalid. The prefix `xsi` is not defined within the XML data. Either remove or declare it:

```
<VacancyList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.com/list.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks Zoff, that didn't work.  Still no results.  0 Rows returned.

Comment: And the XML feed is external, provided by a 3rd party, so I don't think I can remove or declare a variable in there.  Thanks.